# How to stop redirecting to tfs in browser after clicking on new pull request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

After clicking on new pull request it redirects me to the browser from where I have to choose the branches and complete the pull request. I want to complete the PR from inside Team explorer. so how to stop the redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this issue, this is by design, after you connect azure devops in visual studio, clicking the `new pull request` button causes the jump to the azure devops web portal in the browser is normal.

This process is also stated in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=tfs-2018#from-visual-studio):

> Select **New Pull Request** to open up a web browser where you can
>   create the new pull request in the Azure DevOps Services web portal.

**Update**:

If you don't want to redirect to azure devops portal, then you need to install [Pull Requests for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VSIDEVersionControlMSFT.pr4vs) extension in visual studio.

The Pull Requests extension lets you create new pull requests **without** **leaving the IDE**. Review changes, add all the details for the pull request, assign reviewers, and add work items. Use the Build and Code Analysis Results to resolve issues and get green before you submit the PR.

Comment: Yes, but I have seen in other machines from VS when they make a new PR the whole branch selection happens inside the team explorer not in the browser.

Comment: @Souma Without redirecting to the azure devops portal, I think this is because the `Pull Requests for Visual Studio` extension is installed in visual studio. Please view my update